# nodeJS : get response is not opening in browser - says page isnt working

Tags: node.js, express, restful-url

I have created as RestAPI using `node.js` which connects the MySQL server, connections are successful but when I request the URL, the browser keeps loading and says `this page is not working`

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json)
var mySqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
host :'db4free.net',
user:'username',
password:'password',
database:'db'

});

mySqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
if(!err)
console.log('success');
else
console.log('failed' +JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
});


app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('Express server is running at port 
3000'));

app.get('/tasks',(res,req)=>{
mySqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM tasks',(err,rows,fields)=>{
 if(!err)
 console.log(rows[0]);
 else
 console.log(err);
})
});
```

When I try the URL `localhost:3000/tasks`, nothing is loaded in the browser. The output expected is when opening the URL `localhost:3000/tasks`, the row of data should be logged in the console, but instead the URL itself is not opening.

Comment: `console.log(rows[0]);` you're only console logging, you need to send some response as well, like `res.send('Hello' + rows[0])` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `bodyparser.json` function which will return the middleware for your req parsing. You have to include it like below:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Also, you have to end the request to load the data in the browser by sending data or ending the request using `req.json` or `req.end`. You have to swap req, res object in function arguments as `req` comes before `res`.

```
app.get('/tasks',(req, res)=>{
    console.log('fefefe')
    mySqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM tasks',(err,rows,fields)=>{
        if(!err)
            console.log(rows[0]);
        else
            console.log(err);
        res.send({d: rows[0]})
    })
});
```